# Python: Repeat function until its return value matches some function

Tags: python-3.x

I'm having several functions like `RandomNumber(n)` which return a number x < n

Now I would like to have the possibility, to write functions, like `exclude` which let me add filtering expressions to exclude some numbers.

For example:

```
exclude(RandomNumber(100), lambda x: x == 0)
```

should call `RandomNumber(100)` until the return value is `!= 0`. Is this even possible in python?

Comment: Not like that, since the function is called before `exclude()` is invoked.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it in a lambda? `exclude(lambda: RandomNumber(100), lambda x...`

Answer (score 1):

There is the standard `filter` function which might already do what you want. Use it as `filter(predicate, sequence)`, where `predicate = lambda x: x != 0` and sequence would be a list of numbers created with `RandomNumber`.

You can also do:

```
def get_nonzero():
    while True:
        result = RandomNumber(100)
        if result != 0:
            return result
```

That will just call the function until it is non-zero.